# Discord bot sharding for testing purposes, how to test IPC before 1000s of servers

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I’m looking to shard my bot as it grows in usage.  I have the start to my code porting for shard’ing my bot.  I would like to create 2 shards, with 1 server each, so that I can verify all my IPC is correct in a testing environment before pushing it to production.

I don’t see any parameters that allow a “max servers per shard” or something like this, to force some kind of shard affinity.

How to do this in a test environment?

Comment: Well, afaik you can't  limit the number of servers per shard but you can just [spawn multiple shards](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ShardingManager?scrollTo=spawn)

Comment: I don’t see how that helps.  I can create 2 shards already, with the arguments.  What I can’t seem to do is get 1 server on 1 shard, and another server on the 2nd shard.  All the servers get assigned to the first shard.